# Ocultar el primer option del select al desplegar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

tengo un problema que no sé como solucionar.

Tengo un select en el cual aparece por defecto la primera opción seleccionada "Seleccione una opción"

```
<select class="sel">
  <option value="" selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
```

Lo que necesito es, que no sé cómo se hace, que me imagino que será una función js o JQuery para que cuando se despliegue el select esta primera opción de "Seleccione una opción" no aparezca en el desplegable. Con los inputs es más facil ya que poniendo el *placeholder* aparece el texto pero al poner el foco sobre dicho input el texto desaparece.

Me podríais ayudar para saber cómo hacer dicha función para ocultar este option del select cuando se despliegue?

Muchas gracias

Comment: has probado mirar eventos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La solucion seria simple: disabled, entonces quedaría asi:

```html
<select class="sel">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
```

ED: Bueno, no te la ocultaría, pero si que no te dejaría seleccionarla

ED2: Otra opcion, para hacer que esté oculta tambien existe el atributo: hidden

Al estar en primer lugar en tu ejemplo no te haria falta el selected y te quedaría algo asi:

```html
<select class="sel">
  <option value="" hidden>Selecciona una opción</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Tow</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">echt</option>
  <option value="9">nine</option>
  <option value="10">then</option> 
</select>
```

Como me pusieron en un comentario, te pondria un preview de como saldría, pero no tengo muy claro como se hace en esta pagina, disculpa las molestias

Comment: Uy te me adelanteste por 17 segundos. Esa es la forma sencilla que uso para casos como estos. Mi +1. Convendría que lo pongas en codesnippet para que se pueda probar.

Comment: Añadiéndole el atributo `hidden` al `<option>` conseguirías además que no se mostrara al desplegar: `<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Selecciona una opción</option>` Si quieres modifica la respuesta para que lo contemple ^^

Comment: Te me has adelantado, justo estaba haciendo esa edicion ^^' De todos modos, muchas gracias (:

Comment: esta solución me vale para todos los navegadores menos para el explorer que lo acabo de probar ahí y se me sigue viendo el `<option>` de `<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Selecciona una opción</option>`

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción puede ser esta, aunque no seria html.
Deberías colocarlo en tu archivo JS o envolverlo en un `<script></script>` dentro de tu archivo html.

```
$("#inputID").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

Deberias cambiar el `inputID` por el id de tu select.